# How to get the status of spawn process in twisted python?

Tags: python, process, twisted, spawn

I want to trigger many long running processes continiously. And, based on the status returned of each process executed, I need to perform other tasks. In the below example, I'm able to spawn processes, but I'm not able to capture/get the details of the spawn processes execution status returned to mail loop(i.e in CmdProtocol class).

I'm new to this twisted python concepts - Can someone help me here?

```
import sys
from twisted.internet.protocol import ServerFactory, ProcessProtocol
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import protocol
import os
import signal


class MyPP(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_id = os.getpid()

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connectionMade!"
        print "Parent id = %s" % self.parent_id
        print "Child process id = %s" % self.transport.pid

    def outReceived(self, data):
        print "out", data

    def errReceived(self, data):
        print "error", data

    def inConnectionLost(self):
        print "inConnectionLost! stdin is closed! (we probably did it)"
        print "Parent id = %s" % self.parent_id
        print "Child process id closes STDIN= %s" % self.transport.pid    

    def outConnectionLost(self):
        print "outConnectionLost! The child closed their stdout!"
        print "Parent id = %s" % self.parent_id
        print "Child process id closes STDOUT = %s" % self.transport.pid                

    def errConnectionLost(self):
        print "errConnectionLost! The child closed their stderr."
        print "Parent id = %s" % self.parent_id
        print "Child process id closes ERRCONN = %s" % self.transport.pid    

    def processExited(self, reason):
        print "processExited %s, status %d" % (self.transport.pid, reason.value.exitCode,)

    def processEnded(self, reason):
        print "%s processEnded, status %d" % (self.transport.pid, reason.value.exitCode,)
        print "quitting"

class CmdProtocol(LineReceiver):

    delimiter = '\n'
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.client_ip = self.transport.getPeer()
        print "Client connection from %s" % self.client_ip

    def processcmd(self):
        pp = MyPP()
        cmd = ['c:\Python27\python.exe', '-u',  'print_hi.py']
        print "Calling processcmd - <%s>" % cmd
        reactor.spawnProcess(pp, cmd[0], cmd[1:])

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "Lost client connection.  Reason: %s" % reason

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if not line: return
        # Parse the command
        print 'Cmd received from %s : %s' % (self.client_ip, line)
        commandParts = line.split()

        if len(commandParts) > 0:
            command = commandParts[0].lower()
            args = commandParts[1:]
            try:
                print "Command received : <%s>" % command
                method = getattr(self, command)
            except AttributeError, e:
                self.sendLine('Error: no such command.')
            else:
                try:
                    res = method()
                    print "Returned status:%s" % res
                    self.sendLine('Command executed successfully.')                
                except Exception, e:
                    self.sendLine('Error: ' + str(e))     

    def do_kill(self, pid):
        """kill: Kill a process (PID)"""
        print 'Killing pid:%s' % pid
        res = os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGTERM)
        print "Kill Status %s" % res

class MyFactory(ServerFactory):
    protocol = CmdProtocol
    def __init__(self):
        print "Factory called"

reactor.listenTCP(8000, MyFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Here I m planning to implement,

when error occured while executing:
 - <do this>

when started:
 - < do this>

when completed:
 - <do this>

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a very basic Python data structures question.  You just need to refer to an instance of `CmdProtocol` from an instance of `MyPP`.  Since `CmdProtocol` is what constructs `MyPP` in the first place, this is easy.  Just change the construction of `MyPP` to look like this:

```
def processcmd(self):
    pp = MyPP(self)
```

and then `MyPP.__init__` to look like this:

```
def __init__(self, cmd_protocol):
    self.parent_id = os.getpid()
    self.cmd_protocol = cmd_protocol
```

Then, in any method on `MyPP`, you can access the relevant `CmdProtocol` instance with `self.cmd_protocol`.

Comment: But, still I'm not able to get the execution status of the process executed. cmd= ['python.exe','-u','print_hi.py']. Here, print_hi.py is the process being executed. But, After the process is called, I always see a success even though the print_hi.py got some error(syntax error). Only way I can catch the status is, in MyPP.processExited(), where it gives the status code(non-zero for failure). So, when I see some non-zero status, I should call another function to capture that. For that purpose only, I want to get the status in CommandProtocol. Should I use some callback methods here.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You say, "I'm not able to get the execution status" and then you describe, in detail, how you have retrieved the execution status.  You've already figured out the right answer, so if all you need is for me to tell you "yes, go ahead", then yes, go ahead :)

Comment: Sorry - If I'm confusing you. :-( I can get the status inside the MyPP(), but not able to get the status in CmdProtocol. I'm thinking to do some operation upon the status returned, in CmdProtocol. How to transfer the control/status to CmdProtocol, when MyPP.processExited() is being called in MyPP.